# ee.reduceRegion() returns error 'Cannot read property 'count' of undefined'

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, node-js

I'm using google earth engine javascript API with nodeJS and Express. Both the authentication with Eearth Engine API and Initializing the EE API is a success.

I would like to do a pixel count to obtain statistics from a classified image using EE. Both the image input and geometry input are okay but I keep getting the error:

> 'Cannot read property 'count' of undefined'.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Note: The code works fine on google earth engine code editor
Here is the code snippet and the error message I get.

```
 try {
// create an empty list to store area values in
var arealist = [];

// create a function to derive extent of one class
// arguments are class number and class name
var areacount = function (cnr, name) {
  var singleMask = classified.updateMask(classified.eq(cnr)); // mask a single class
  console.log("This is the image input:",singleMask.getInfo());
  console.log("This is the geometry input:",area)
  var stats = singleMask.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(), // count pixels in a single class
    geometry: area,
    scale: 30,
  });

  var pix = ee.Number(stats.get("sum"));
  var hect = pix.multiply(100).divide(10000); // pixel = 10m x 10m --> 100 sqm
 
  arealist.push({
    Class: name,
    Pixels: pix,
    Hectares: hect,
    // Percentage: perc,
  });
};

// severity classes in different order
var names2 = [
  "NA",
  "High Severity",
  "Moderate-high Severity",
  "Moderate-low Severity",
  "Low Severity",
  "Unburned",
  "Enhanced Regrowth, Low",
  "Enhanced Regrowth, High",
];

// execute function for each class
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  areacount(i, names2[i]);
}

console.log(
  "Area by class",
  arealist,
);} 
catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

Here is the console logs and the error:

```
Express is listening on localhost:3000
Authenticated with the Earth Engine API
Initialized the Earth Engine API
{ type: 'MultiPolygon', coordinates: [ [ [Array] ] ] }
projects/earthengine-legacy/maps/0f99da2c9461ee7d6be825cb5bdc005f-3439921616377d62dc55e77adee38adf mapid 1 ---->
projects/earthengine-legacy/maps/835b19e303269e381ca28266d3208f60-806ede73ed203a67ce3296f696ef1b6d mapid 2
This is the image input: {
  type: 'Image',
  bands: [
    {
      id: 'sum',
      data_type: [Object],
      crs: 'EPSG:4326',
      crs_transform: [Array]
    }
  ]
}
This is the geometry input: {
  func: null,
  args: null,
  varName: null,
  type_: 'MultiPolygon',
  coordinates_: [ [ [Array] ] ],
  geometries_: null,
  geodesic_: undefined,
  evenOdd_: undefined
}
TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined
    at areacount (/home/derick/Desktop/goeserverrest/modules/geeScript.js:153:29)
    at getGeeRaster (/home/derick/Desktop/goeserverrest/modules/geeScript.js:183:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/derick/Desktop/goeserverrest/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/derick/Desktop/goeserverrest/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at /home/derick/Desktop/goeserverrest/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:137:5
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (async_hooks.js:197:9)
    at invokeCallback (/home/derick/Desktop/goeserverrest/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:231:16)
    at done (/home/derick/Desktop/goeserverrest/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:220:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/derick/Desktop/goeserverrest/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:280:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:412:35)
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you haven't initialized the Earth Engine library. 99% of the functions are dynamically generated during initialization.

```
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-initialize
```

Comment: I had followed the instructions from https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/demos/server-auth-nodejs/server.js to authenticate and initialize EE. I have also used other EE library functions without an error. Does it mean that the functions are partially loaded?

Comment: Thank you very much. I realized that I had ee.reset() on my code and that was what was causing the issue. I removed it and now the code works fine.